# i want to store the resultant of sum of column "Value" with the same ID into another table

Tags: sql

[Hi Guys this is my Table called "SAM"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb8kT.png)

[Result: sum of column "Value" with the same ID:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNa16.png)

Now i want to store the result to another table.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Hint: `GROUP BY` and `SUM`.  Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Yes i have, tried this is the query:   select S_Date, TID, sum(Value)
from SAM
group by S_Date, TID

Comment: And that looks correct to me, so what is the problem?

Comment: Try an `insert select` if you want to do a query.  Or a subquery with a join if you are doing an update

Comment: it will just show the result, but i want to store it to another table. Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: got it :)  thankq....   MiltoxBeyond

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for **insert**

```
INSERT INTO result_table (S_Date, TID, Value) 
VALUES (select S_Date, TID, sum(Value) from SAM group by S_Date, TID);
```

Try this for **Update**

Create temporary table

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (S_Date Date,TID INT,Value INT);
INSERT INTO temp_table (select S_Date, TID, sum(Value) 
from SAM group by S_Date, TID);
UPDATE resul_table JOIN temp_table ON resul_table.TID = temp_table.TID 
SET resul_table.S_Date = temp_table.S_Date, resul_table.Value = temp_table.Value
```

**Please use the datatype in temp table same as your table**

Also run these three queries for update in same time.
If you run these seperately, it wont work.

Comment: Thankq Sarvan Kumar, thought to ask question for updating values insted of inserting and making duplicate values ur comment gave me the answer i need. :)